# FragmentManager begin transaction without container id

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_view,mapFragment).commit();
```

As we know that, this way we can load or replace `Fragment`

**But**
In this `snippet` we are passing fragment container id.

**Is there any way**
to load fragment without passing ID or pass `FragmentContainerView` instead of id

Comment: Why not just assign your view an ID (programatically, not in XML) and then pass that ID to the replace method?

Answer (score 0):

you can use navigation graph action to navigate between fragments with one line of code like that :

```
 Navigation.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.action_fragment1_to_fragment2)
```

provided that :

- you have a navigation graph that looks like this

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment_1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
        android:name="Your.Package.Fragment_1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_1_layout">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment1_to_fragment2"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_2" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_2"
        android:name="Your.Package.Fragment_2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_2_layout">
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

- and you've written the correct code to setup your activity with navigation components.

If you don't know what is navigation components I highly recommend taking the navigation lab on android developers where it should instruct you how to setup your project with it.

[Learn Jetpack Navigation | Android Developers (Java)](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation#0)

for more information about navigation components and fragments follow these links and start reading Android Developers Tutorials.

[Fragments| Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments)

[Navigation Components | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation)